# NGINX web server configuration

Tags: nginx, dns, server, webserver

I've just downloaded NGINX for Windows and I'm struggeling a bit. 
It's up and running with my index file showing at *127.0.0.1:8080*, but I'm having problems with connection my web server to my domain.

From what I understand from the documentation I've read online, I had to change the DNS properties at my registrar like this (target-IP is my public IP):

[image: DNS A property]

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  erikbugge.no www.erikbugge.no;

        location / {
            root   www;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   www;
        }
    }
}
```

I have also port-forwarded port 8080 to my local IP address in my router.

The problem now is that whenever I'm trying to access my webpage *www.erikbugge.no* it simply redirects me to my public IP address.
I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, but I have no idea what it is.

Please be gentle, I'm new to this web server stuff.

Comment: offtopic: hiding IP address while showing domain name is quite meaningless

Comment: I guess you tries to setup server on you home machine? It's probably bad idea, because your ISP and/or firewall will prevent this.

Comment: Oh, btw, nginx on Windows is still in beta (and I doubt it will be released anytime soon) http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html

Comment: I don't get it. Why would my ISP prevent me from having a web server at home? And yes, I'm considering installing a Linux distro on my old PC. Would that work, or would it still be prevented by a firewall and my ISP?

Comment: Because that's a common way for viruses, trojans etc. I don't say your ISP definitely does so, but usually ISPs block incoming connections to common ports. You should contact your ISP (or find out this information somehow).

Comment: Okay, I will. Thanks for the response.